Execute Karate Feature file through Runner.java for Performance Testing
I am a beginner in Gatling and Karate. The Automation team had created a test suite which consists of multiple feature files for various APIs and they had used the Runner.java to simulate the test. I want to use the same test suite. So is there a way to enhance the runner.java for the Performance tests by invoking the feature files in the scenarios?
I tried using the below code in the Runner.java file but it didn't work.
Error Message

Hi there, please add your code in your question (you can format it by adding it between three back-ticks ), don't use screenshots. The problem you are seeing is that you are missing a library on your project that is what Cannot resolve symbol means. So you either have the wrong imports or missing a library.

Can you please check this link: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/blob/d7d47ecd824904f51faaa826ef163ba92f32607a/src/test/java/app/perf/TodoSimulation.java
